# The case of the vanishing symbols

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, debug-symbols

I have a single solution containing several projects but am only running two right now.
Project 1 runs as a windows service in Release mode but runs as a console app in Debug mode. Project 2 is an MMC snapin (output type=class library). They communicate via WCF.

**TIME A**

When I first started debugging yesterday after a fresh build my callstack window showed this:

```
lines in service...
[External Code]
--Transition from Client to Server --
lines in client...
```

I could double-click any line to go to that line. I could set breakpoints in either project and they would be hit.

**TIME B** (Sometime later in the day)

I started seeing flags on breakpoints in the client (project 2) indicating *"The breakpoint will not currently be hit. The source code is different from the original version"* even though I just rebuilt all projects. I had made a few code changes but (as far as I know) no project or build changes. I did a solution "clean" but that did not help. The call stack still worked the same as during TIME A.

**TIME C** (Next day--this morning)

I rebooted. I deleted all obj and bin directories. I rebuilt the entire solution and launched hoping a fresh start would improve the situation. Now it is worse. Breakpoints are flagged with *"The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document."* The call stack has deteriorated to showing the client as external code:

```
lines in service...
[External Code]
--Transition from Client to Server --
[External Code]
```

- If I select **show external code** in the call stack it lists lines from the client assembly (mixed in with system assemblies of course) but all greyed out. In the Module window (debug >> windows >> module) the client assembly is **not** listed.
- If I select **symbol load information** from a line in the call stack it shows *"cannot find or open the PDB file"* for 5 different locations, the most curious one being under my project's obj/Release directory--not the obj/Debug directory--even though my project is set to Debug configuration.
- If I select **load symbols** from a line in the call stack then select the pdb file in either my obj/Debug or bin/Debug directory, it reports *"A matching symbol file was not found in this folder"*.
- Configuration manager shows that all projects are set to Debug configuration and all are included in the build.

---

I have reviewed similar SO questions, which helped me find all the above things to examine, but have not yet found any rhyme or reason to my situation.

*How can I save Visual Studio from its delirium and recover my lost symbols?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, Visual Studio, as I should have expected, it was me, not you. You have, through thick and thin [clients], continued to show your steadfast support [functions]. Can we still be [virtual] friends? It boils down to a difference in our cultures. I take things at face value; you like to bury yourself in your registry data, ignoring my MMC snapin code that was right in front of you shouting *"I'm here, I'm here!"*.

Sigh.

I'm here.

I mean, just because it did not replace your last relationship with [InstallUtil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc303697.aspx) is that any reason to dredge up the past, bringing those long-forgotten bits [of code] to the surface, keeping the dll forever separate from the pdb? Apparently you think so. Aye, there's the rub! I just did not understand you, but now I do.

Oh, yes; now I do.